# How to update a <span> in jQuery (Shopify Quickview feature)

Tags: jquery, html, shopify

I want to add a baseprice to a Quickview feature in Shopify, but I am not able to get everything right with jquery. I want to calculate the basePase on basis of the productPrice. The problem is, that the calculation isnt shown in the HTML. It seems, that I am missing something.  is still empty. In another context (Shopify Liquid Code) this modification was quite simply. Here it seems to be more complex. Has anyone an idea / solution for this? Thanks for your help!

```js
  Shopify.doNotTriggerClickOnThumb = false; 
                                       
  var selectCallbackQuickview = function(variant, selector) {
      var productItem = jQuery('.quick-view .product-item');
          addToCart = productItem.find('.add-to-cart-btn'),
          productPrice = productItem.find('.price'),
          comparePrice = productItem.find('.compare-price'),
          basePrice = productItem.find('.base-price'),
          totalPrice = productItem.find('.total-price span');           
      
    
        // Regardless of stock, update the product price
        productPrice.html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}"));
    
        // Also update and show the product's compare price if necessary
        if ( variant.compare_at_price > variant.price ) {
          comparePrice
            .html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, "{{ shop.money_format }}"))
            .show();
          productPrice.addClass('on-sale');
        } else {
          comparePrice.hide();
          productPrice.removeClass('on-sale');
        }
       
       BASEPRICE IS CALCULATED HERE:
       if ( productPrice > 20 ){
        if ( productPrice > 90) {
        basePrice = productPrice / 75 / 12 * 100;
        }
        basePrice = productPrice / 75 / 6 * 100;
       else {
          basePrice = productPrice / 75 * 100;
        }
    
      /*recaculate total price*/
        //try pattern one before pattern 2
        var regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
        var unitPriceTextMatch = jQuery('.quick-view .price').text().match(regex);

        if (!unitPriceTextMatch) {
          regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
          unitPriceTextMatch = jQuery('.quick-view .price').text().match(regex);     
        }

        if (unitPriceTextMatch) {
          var unitPriceText = unitPriceTextMatch[0];     
          var unitPrice = unitPriceText.replace(/[.|,]/g,'');
          var quantity = parseInt(jQuery('.quick-view input[name=quantity]').val());
          var totalPrice = unitPrice * quantity;

          var totalPriceText = Shopify.formatMoney(totalPrice, window.money_format);
          regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;     
          if (!totalPriceText.match(regex)) {
            regex = /([0-9]+[.|,][0-9]+)/g;
          } 
          totalPriceText = totalPriceText.match(regex)[0];

          var regInput = new RegExp(unitPriceText, "g"); 
          var totalPriceHtml = jQuery('.quick-view .price').html().replace(regInput ,totalPriceText);
          jQuery('.quick-view .total-price span').html(totalPriceHtml);     
        }
    /*end of price calculation*/

  };
```

```html
            <div class="prices">
              <span class="compare-price"></span>
              <span class="price"></span>
              <span class="base-price">BASEPRICE SHOULD BE SEEN HERE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is a base price? Most shops stick with just a price, and perhaps a slashed out compare at price if they want to provide the illusion of some kind of deal.

Comment: If you sell a bottle of wine (there is often 0,75 L in it) - The base price is the price for 1 L - In the EU you must gave the customer the option to compare prices with the "base price". So all kinds of bottles, 0.75, 0.5 L can be easily compared. Baseprice = Cost per 1 L of the product. - I have implemented it on all sites, but now I also want to use it in an "products quickview" feature, where I cannot use Liquid Code :) I am an jQuery newbie :D

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
$('.base-price').text(basePrice);
```

This find the element(s) with classname '`base-price`' and sets the text to the value of `basePrice`.